Continuous functions that agree on a dense subset but that are not equal
If two continuous functions $f;g: E \to E'$ agree on a dense subset of the topological space $E$ and $E'$ is Hausdorff, then $f \equiv g$.
However, if $E'=\{a,b\}; \mathcal{T'}=\{\emptyset,\{a\}, \{a,b \} \}$;
$$f: \mathbb{R} \to E'; \\ \; x \mapsto a$$
$$
 g:\  \mathbb{R} \to E' \\
    \qquad \qquad \quad \ x \mapsto \begin{cases} a; \ x \neq 0\\
       b; \ x=0 \end{cases}
$$
Then $g^{-1}(\{a\})= \mathbb{R}-\{0\}$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$ and so, $g$ is continuous and as $D=\mathbb{R}-\{0\}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, we have that $f;g$ agree on $D$ but $f(0) \neq g(0)$. Is this a valid example? Any other examples would be welcome

Consider the line with two origins $0,0'$. Let $f$ be the identity function except at $0'$ with $f(0')=0$. Similarly let $g$ be the identity function except at $0$ with $g(0)=0'$.
